# Why is AWSDynamoDBScanExpression returning empty when using sort key as filterExpression?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have the following DynamoDB table:

```
BoardId   |  DateTime          |  Data  |  Type
-------------------------------------------------
1         |  20180424T123508Z  |  68.1  |  U
1         |  20181026T143233Z  |  38.2  |  T
1         |  20190108T120150Z  |  38.1  |  T
2         |  20180425T092311Z  |  63.4  |  U
```

"BoardId" is the **partition key** and "DateTime" is the **sort key**.

I want to fetch the entry with "BoardId"="1" and "DateTime" containing "2019".
I used [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper#scan](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/Classes/AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.html#//api/name/scan:expression:completionHandler:) to do this with the following code:

```
    let dbObjMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()

    let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
    scanExpression.limit = 10
    scanExpression.filterExpression = "#id = :id AND contains(#dt, :dt)"
    scanExpression.expressionAttributeNames = [
        "#id" : "BoardId",
        "#dt" : "DateTime"
    ]
    scanExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [
        ":id" : "1",
        ":dt" : "2019"
    ]

    dbObjMapper
        .scan(Event.self, expression: scanExpression)
        .continueWith(block: {
            (task: AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
            } else if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
                print("The request was successful.")
                print(paginatedOutput.items.count)
                for event in paginatedOutput.items as! [Event] {
                    print(event)
                }
            }
            return ()
    })
```

But I am getting an empty result. There is no error ("*The request was successful.*") but printing `paginatedOutput.items.count` is 0. I expected to get the same result when doing the same Scan from the DynamoDB web console:

[image: dynamodb console]

What is wrong with my usage of `AWSDynamoDBScanExpression`?

I tried using other Scan configurations:

- do not set `filterExpression` => **OK**, returns up to 10 items
- `#id = :id` => **OK**, returns up to 10 items with BoardId=1
- `contains(#dt, :dt)` => no error but also returns empty results
- set the `scanExpression.indexName` to some Index where "DateTime" **is not** the sort key (ex. "BoardId" is the **partition key** and "Type" is the **sort key**) => **OK**, returns the correct item same as the web console

Is it not allowed to use the sort key as a filter expression?

There is no mention of this in the [AWS SDK for iOS docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/Classes/AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.html) or in the [AWS Working with Scan docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html) (it is even stated here that "*With Scan, you can specify any attributes in a filter expression—including partition key and sort key attributes*")

Comment: Note you shouldn't be using a scan here, instead Query (id = 1 , DateTime starts with 2019)

Comment: @Charles Thanks for the tip! After reading your comment, I found this [Performance Considerations for Scans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html#bp-query-scan-performance), so yeah, I will have to change from Scan to Query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try removing `scanExpression.limit = 10` from your scan parameters.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-Limit: "The maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of matching items)."

So what is probably happening is that the scan is looking at 10 items, then applying the filter, the filter matches none of them, and you get no results

Comment: Wow, that did solve my problem! It seems I misunderstood how `limit` works. So the `limit` is applied **before** the filter (it got 10 whatever items first **then** applied the filter).